# How to calculate size of a structure in c for pipe reading?

Tags: c, memory, pipe, malloc, structure

A structure `s1` which contains several another structure `s2` and the number of `s2` - `s1_length`. `s2` includes a set of int - `arr` and its length -`s2_length`. I want to write `s1` into pipe in child process and read it in parent process. But I got `segmentation falut` all the time. I guess there was something wrong with the size of calculated structure `s1`. But I really could not find where exactly was wrong there.

My code was like this :

```
struct s1{
 int s1_length;
 struct s2 *s2;
};

struct s2{
 int s2_length;
 int *arr;
};

int getSize(int s_length, int *s2_length_arr){
    int i, sum = 0;
    for(i=0; i< s.length; i++){
        sum += sizeof(int) * (arr_length[i] + 1);
    }
    sum += sizeof(int);
    return sum;
}

void main(){
    ...
    int i;
    int *fds = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10 *2);

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        pipe(fds +i*2);

    struct s1 s;
    struct s2 ss;
    s.s1_length = 0;
    int s_size, sum;
    int *s2_length_arr;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
       child_pid = fork();
       if(child_pid == 0){
           close(fds[i*2]);

           // do something
           // return `s1` include 10 `s2`
           s = getS(...);

           // return a int array, with the length of `arr` of every `s2`
           s2_length_arr = getS2LengthArray(...);
           sum = getSize(s.length, s2_length_arr);

           write(fds[i*2+1], &s_length, sizeof(int));
           write(fds[i*2+1], &s2_length_arr, sizeof(int)*s_length);
           write(fds[i*2+1], &s, sum);
           close(fds[i*2+1]);
           exit(0);
       } 
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
       close(fds[i*2+1]);
       read(fds[i*2], &s_length, sizeof(int));
       read(fds[i*2], &s2_length_arr, sizeof(int) * s_length);
       struct s1 s;
       s.s2 = malloc(sizeof(struct s2) * s_length);
       for(j=0; j<s_length; j++)
           s.s2[j].arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * s2_length_arr[j]);
       read(fds[i*2], &s, sum);
       close(fds[i*2]);
    }
}
```

As result, reading `s_length`, `s2_length_arr` and 'sum' were normal,but failed to read `s` with `segmentation fault`. Does anyone know what went wrong here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors, but it looks like you're not serializing and deserializing properly.  Try to create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks for your reply. But I did make a "minimal reproducible example". The code above is extracted from my code, which only relates to my question. Due to the "syntax errors", I would improve it a bit. But I don't understand what ado you mean by serializing and deserializing here?

Comment: [Serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) is the process of converting a data structure into a byte stream for storage or transmission.  Deserialization is the reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you're best off separating your serialization/deserialization code from your computation code, putting it in separate read and write functions.  So you might have something like:

```
// read/write checking for errors
void read_check(int fd, void *buffer, size_t len) {
    char *p = buffer;
    while (len > 0) {
        size_t rlen = read(fd, p, len);
        if (rlen <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected error/eof reading from %d\n", fd);
            exit(1); }
        p += rlen;
        len -= rlen }
}
void write_check(int fd, void *buffer, size_t len) {
    char *p = buffer;
    while (len > 0) {
        size_t wlen = write(fd, p, len);
        if (wlen <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected error/eof writing to %d", fd);
            exit(1); }
        p += wlen;
        len -= wlen; }
}

struct s1{
    int s1_length;
    struct s2 *s2;
};

struct s2{
    int s2_length;
    int *arr;
};

void write_s2(int fd, struct s2 *p) {
    write_check(fd, &p->s2_length, sizeof(p->s2_length));
    write_check(fd, p->arr, p->s2_length * sizeof(*p->arr));
}
void write_s1(int fd, struct s1 *p) {
    write_check(fd, &p->s1_length, sizeof(p->s1_length));
    for (int i = 0; i < p->s1_length; ++i)
        write_s2(fd, &p->s2[i]);
}
void read_s2(int fd, struct s2 *p) {
    read_check(fd, &p->s2_length, sizeof(p->s2_length));
    p->arr = malloc(p->s2_length * sizeof(*p->arr));
    if (!p->arr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ran out of memory\n");
        exit(1); }
    read_check(fd, p->arr, p->s2_length * sizeof(*p->arr));
}
void read_s1(int fd, struct s1 *p) {
    read_check(fd, &p->s1_length, sizeof(p->s1_length));
    p->s2 = malloc(p->s1_length * sizeof(*p->s2));
    if (!p->s2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ran out of memory\n");
        exit(1); }
    for (int i = 0; i < p->s1_length; ++i)
        read_s2(fd, &p->s2[i]);
}
```

Then you'd just call `write_s1` in the child to write the whole linked data structure, and `read_s1` in the parent to read it back.  You probably also want to write a `free_s1` function to free the memory allocated by `read_s1`

You'll generally end up wanting a `read_`, `write_` and `free_` (and possibly `create_`) function for every struct type in your program.  You can also do things with standardizing type sizes and byte order to allow communicating data structures between different machines with different architectures.

Comment: mmmh, so is it simply impossible just pass `s1` in once, even if he right size is allocated?

Comment: your solution runs perfectly!! thanks a lot! (although I still don't know what exactly went wrong if only outer structure is sent)